# How to append double quotes to a table name in JPA entity class table name?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jpa

I have a table "test" in oracle db under schema "MYSCHEMA".

`select * from MYSCHEMA."test" works fine, but select * from MYSCHEMA.test` gives an error:

> table or view does not exist

I am trying to fetch data from this table using JPA query (Java Spring application).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"test\"", schema = "MYSCHEMA")
public Class MyClass {

}
```

Even if i use double quotes around the table name, the JPA query gives "table or view does not exist" error. How to resolve it?

I am not supposed to edit/rename the table name as the table/db is already linked to some existing applications.

Comment: Some JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus) do that for you, while others insist that you have to handle it yourself. Which JPA provider is yours?

Comment: Its EclipseLink  Neil Stockton

Comment: You might be able to use the `delimited-identifiers` element in your `persistence-unit-defaults`. Of course, that will affect all your other identifiers and might cause other problems....

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test", schema = "MYSCHEMA")
public Class MyClass {
}
```

only single quote around table name

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nilesh Jadav. I have tried adding single quotes around the table name and tried without adding anything to the table name as well. It is also giving same error.

Comment: please read 8th and 9th point, might help you ! https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm

Answer (score -1):

jpa provide another way to quote names of tables by adding ` to till it not to escape double quotes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`test`", schema = "MYSCHEMA")
public Class MyClass {
}
```